# Built-in LTE PCI modem on HP EliteBook 850 G5 not recognized under Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm trying to run an LTE modem on an HP EliteBook 850 G5. But it seems that it's not recognized by the system. I get a message from the modem manager:

> ModemManager[417]:   Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0': not supported by any plugin
>   ModemManager[417]:   Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin

```
$ sudo systemctl status ModemManager.service
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-07-06 19:43:46 CEST; 1h 44min ago
Main PID: 417 (ModemManager)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
    Memory: 6.8M
    CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
       └─417 /usr/bin/ModemManager

systemd[1]: Starting Modem Manager...
ModemManager[417]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.8.0) starting in system bus...
systemd[1]: Started Modem Manager.
ModemManager[417]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0': not supported by any plugin
ModemManager[417]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin

$ uname -r
4.17.2-1-ARCH

$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:01
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/pci_bus/0000:01':
  KERNEL=="0000:01"
  SUBSYSTEM=="pci_bus"
  DRIVER==""
  ATTR{cpuaffinity}=="ff"
  ATTR{cpulistaffinity}=="0-7"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0':
  KERNELS=="0000:00:1c.0"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
  DRIVERS=="pcieport"
  ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
  ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
  ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
  ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="2.5 GT/s"
  ATTRS{current_link_width}=="1"
  ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
  ATTRS{device}=="0x9d13"
  ATTRS{devspec}==""
  ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
  ATTRS{enable}=="1"
  ATTRS{irq}=="19"
  ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
  ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
  ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="8 GT/s"
  ATTRS{max_link_width}=="1"
  ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
  ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
  ATTRS{revision}=="0xf1"
  ATTRS{secondary_bus_number}=="1"
  ATTRS{subordinate_bus_number}=="1"
  ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x83b2"
  ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
  ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
  KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
  SUBSYSTEMS==""
  DRIVERS==""

$ sudo /sbin/lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5914] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [103c:83b2]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620 [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub [8086:9d35] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d13] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:9d16] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E [8086:9d4e] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E [103c:83b2]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PMC [103c:83b2]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [8086:15d8] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [103c:83b2]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
3b:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7360] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8337]
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0116]
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Please edit question with output of `lspci -nn` so we can identify the PCI devices.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your attention. I have added needed output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "Wireless controller" at `3b:00.0` is the PCI LTE modem; googling the id `8086:7360` confirms this.

So the modem manager messages are spurious.

Googling also turns up [this](https://mobile.twitter.com/intel/status/981701464040136705?lang=de) tweet from April 2018 which makes it look like there's currently no driver for this device in the Linux kernel.